# Current Working Directory is not Cordova-based project

Tags: android, node.js, cordova

Below is the exact command I did but not sure why I was unable to add android platform using the command 'cordova platform add android'

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Do this

```
cordova create folder_name com.company_name.someid "App Name"
```

Folder name without space.(I'm not sure it'll work with space or not)

Then

```
cd folder_name

cordova platform add android
```